# Reshape DataFrame - Convert column value with duplicates to column header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. The first columns has string df[0]=[a,b,c]*5.My second column has corresponding values[cat,dog,4...etc].I want to change the shape of dataframe.

```
               0                   1
0           ITEM         cat
1   MANUFACTURER         queen
2          MODEL               black
3           COST              5
4           ITEM          dog
5   MANUFACTURER                god
6          MODEL   All-in-Wonder White
7           COST              50
```

I want Item Manufacturer Model and Cost as column Names and corresponding values in rows.

Comment: the question is not very clear. can you create like a sample dataframe which depicts the logic you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Output is similar to what @jakevdp has answered. HardCoding data['index']works for this solution. How shud we go about for large data sets?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [pandas.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) operation.

For your data, it might look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    0: 2 * ["ITEM", "MANUFACTURER", "MODEL", "COST"],
    1: ["cat", "queen", "black", 5, "dog", "god", "All-in-Wonder White", 50]
})

# Encode how rows should be grouped
data['index'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]

data.pivot(values=1, columns=0, index='index')
```

```
0     COST ITEM MANUFACTURER                MODEL
index                                            
1        5  cat        queen                black
2       50  dog          god  All-in-Wonder White
```

Comment: you have a small typo: change df to data (or reverse)

Comment: instead of hardcoding the `index ` column, you can try `df[0].eq('ITEM').cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    0: 2 * ["ITEM", "MANUFACTURER", "MODEL", "COST"],
    1: ["cat", "queen", "black", 5, "dog", "god", "All-in-Wonder White", 50]
})
transformed_data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(data
         .groupby(0)
         .agg(lambda x: tuple(x))
         .reset_index()
         .to_dict(orient='split')['data'])
)
```